# Will a Nikkor AF-S 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6 G IF-ED VR lens work on my Sony A900?

Tags: lens, nikon, sony, lens-mount

I have a Sony A900 that I want to use with Nikkor AF-S 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6 G IF-ED VR. Does this lens come with a Sony mount? I do not want to have to use an adapter.

Comment: As an aside, just how were you expecting to get a wider field of view from a lens that has the same minimum focal length and a *longer* maximum focal length? That wouldn't give you a wider field of view, but it *would* let you get an even narrower one if you wanted. You want a wider lens, one with a shorter focal length than 70mm available.

Answer (score 2):

No. In general, Nikon make lenses only for Nikon cameras. I'm sure there are one or two exceptions out there, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant get it fit on your camera you always have an adapter to aid the mounts of the lens

Comment: But the OP said that they didn't want to use an adapter, and they may well quite like having aperture control and autofocus as well.

Comment: There are no adapters Nikon F -> Sony A.